# interface function and readonly property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I read new code written in TypeScript and I found something I didn't understand.

```
interface test {
  (a: number): number;
  readonly b: number;
}
```

I know `(a:number): number` means a function, argument is `a:number` and return value is `number`, but I don't know what `readonly b: number` means in this code.

I tested bottom code, but it does not match.

```
const c: test = (a) => {
  this.b = 1
  return a
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a different type to create the function and change the type:

```
interface test {
  (a: number): number;
  readonly b: number;
}

interface test2 {
  (a: number): number;
  b: number;
}

let c = (function (this: test2, a: number) { this.b = 1; return a; }) as test;
```

You can't use an arrow function in your code. Arrow functions don't capture `this`. If you want to use an arrow function, you have to do this in two steps:

```
interface test {
  (a: number): number;
  readonly b: number;
}

interface test2 {
  (a: number): number;
  b: number;
}

let c = ((a: number) => { return a; }) as test2;
c.b = 1;
let d: test = c;
```